# How to find all the dates within last 6 months using Python ?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm doing queries find all the dates within last 6 months using Python and SQLAlchemy. The code is as following,

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
six_months_ago = current_time -  datetime.timedelta(weeks = 24)
puppies = session.query(Puppy).filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth > six_months_ago).all()

for puppy in puppies:
    puppy.name, puppy.dateOfBirth
```

Now, how do I use month's directly in the code than using weeks ? I have seen an elegant solution, but, that uses an external library. I would like to do this w/o installing another library.

Comment: Please clarify your question, `how do I use month's directly in the code than using weeks`.. Do you want to just get the month numbers? Month names? Your code as posted doesn't make this clear.

Comment: I'm using `weeks  = 24` and that is 6 months. Can I use month's directly in the code somehow ?
6 Months = 4 * 6 weeks = 24 weeks

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: Where is your answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

six_months = date.today() - relativedelta(months=+6)
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this with the out-of-the-box tools.

Comment: Hello,
 
How to install this python-dateutil package ? I'm mainly Java developer and have little experience with Python. Can I use pip or homebrew for the installation ?

Comment: `pip install python-dateutil` but you really should be using a virtualenv. You should further give me an upvote, especially if the answer worked for you.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot for the solution. what's virtualenv ? I just open the terminal and install using pip.

Comment: virtualenvs are used to isolate your python version. Sort of like you'd use maven-shade-plugin to create an uberjar so you could simply run your application using `java -jar` without having to specify a classpath hundreds of characters long.