# Python: Format datetime string in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I currently have the following where the AllergiesList can be one or more `dicts`.

```
{
  "AllergiesList": [
    {
      "Date": "2021-09-03T00:00:00",
      "Description": "string",
      "Source": "string",
      "Severity": "string",
      "Reaction": "string",
      "TypeCode": "string",
      "Notes": "string",
      "Notes1": "string",
      "TenancyDescription": "string"
    }
  ],
  "TotalItemCount": 0
}
```

My question is how would I format the `Date` key within all dictionaries to be in a specific format e.g. `d/m/Y`

I currently have the following to remove `dicts` that are more than X months old

```
def is_recent(entry,amount):
    limit_time = pd.Timestamp.today() - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=amount)
    return pd.to_datetime(entry["Date"]) > limit_time
```

Used as follows:

```
allergies = session["allergies"] # This is the same as the code snippet above i.e. a list of dictionaries
session["allergies"] = [entry for entry in allergies["AllergiesList"] if is_recent(entry,6)]
```

Would I need to do another `def()` or can my current one be amended to do what's needed?

Comment: Why do this with `pandas`?

Comment: `session["allergies"]` is a list of dicts like the one you posted?

Comment: @timgeb That is correct

Comment: @I'mahdi because that was the highest upvoted answer given to me previously on another question

Comment: If you are not otherwise using `pandas` it's an overkill - just use datetime module

Comment: Then I don't quite get what the problem is, since you seem to have basic programming knowledge. `for dict_ in something['AllergiesList']: dict_['Date'] = algorithm(dict_['Date'])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: @timgeb it was more whether I could incorporate it into my existing `def` or not

Comment: yes you can add more code to functions (?!)

Comment: Wow! You can? Amazing. I knew StackOverflow would be really helpful today. Thanks. I mean, the question was how I would do that but here we are...

Comment: With regards to finding recent dates - check  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37385078/4046632 or work with `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: That's not what I am asking

Comment: I know - you are asking about changing string format and I already suggested a dupe for that. Mu second comment was related to your use of pandas for something that can be done easily without it. Take it or leave it - it's up to you.

Comment: The question was how I'd integrate it into my list comprehension mostly

Comment: You need to write a function that will take a dict as argument, modify the str and return the new dict. Your current one cannot serve that purpose if you want to use list comprehension. However, you can modify your current function and turn it into generator that will take a list of dicts and yield only recent dicts, after it modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

rec_list = {
    "AllergiesList": [
        {
            "Date": "2021-09-03T00:00:00",
            "Description": "string",
            "Source": "string",
            "Severity": "string",
            "Reaction": "string",
            "TypeCode": "string",
            "Notes": "string",
            "Notes1": "string",
            "TenancyDescription": "string"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2021-09-09T00:00:00",
            "Description": "string",
            "Source": "string",
            "Severity": "string",
            "Reaction": "string",
            "TypeCode": "string",
            "Notes": "string",
            "Notes1": "string",
            "TenancyDescription": "string"
        }
    ],
    "TotalItemCount": 0
}

for rec in rec_list["AllergiesList"]:
    rec["Date"] = datetime.strptime(rec["Date"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(rec_list)
```

Using above code snippet you can convert your all date format records as per your requirment.

**Output:-**

```
{
    "AllergiesList": [
        {
            "Date": "03/09/2021",
            "Description": "string",
            "Source": "string",
            "Severity": "string",
            "Reaction": "string",
            "TypeCode": "string",
            "Notes": "string",
            "Notes1": "string",
            "TenancyDescription": "string",
        },
        {
            "Date": "09/09/2021",
            "Description": "string",
            "Source": "string",
            "Severity": "string",
            "Reaction": "string",
            "TypeCode": "string",
            "Notes": "string",
            "Notes1": "string",
            "TenancyDescription": "string",
        },
    ],
    "TotalItemCount": 0,
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

just replace is_recent function with following one

```
import datetime 

def is_recent(entry, amount):
    limit_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(months=amount)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(entry["Date"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') > limit_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will convert the given format to DD/MM/YYYY

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = entry['Date']
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
date = date_time_obj.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print('Date String:', date)
```

If you want DD/MM/YY format replace `%Y` with `%y` in `date_time_obj.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`